# Security against backward-changes in git?

Tags: git

In particular, is it theoretically possible to make changes to the central (bare; or not) git repository (i.e. having full access to the system it is on) so that the changes do not appear (as a commit) / do not cause conflict on update, but appear in newly cloned repositories?

Or any other similar “forgery”-like change.

Comment: No idea what you're talking about.  You can't "hide" git commits.  It would be very obvious who introduced bad code, if that's what you are worried about.  https://github.com/blog/228-playing-the-blame-game

Comment: Not necessarily in the context of code. Not necessarily as commits: for example, is it possible to change some older commits without causing a conflict on update?

Comment: You might be interested in [this thread](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/210320/focus=210630) on the main Git list.

Comment: And actually you might find [searching that list](http://dir.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git) for words like "collision" and "attack" to be of interest as this topic is quite recurrent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that’s not possible. Every object in Git is uniquely identified by the hash of its content. That also means that when changing the content, the hash would change, causing it to become a new object which is unrelated to the original object.

So even if you changed some contents, you would have to update its identifier (to make Git accept it) and then you would basically have the same effect as when you rebase things. Other people will get those objects when cloning (e.g. when a branch points on it), but those new objects are incompatible to the original objects causing conflicts.

Git checks the validity of objects when cloning and will inform you if objects are missing/corrupt. You can also force a validation of the local object repository by using `git fsck`. The output for a changed object would look like this then:

```
error: sha1 mismatch a98bf3503443ea6a69779fef1f6204fdae913124
error: a98bf3503443ea6a69779fef1f6204fdae913124: object corrupt or missing
missing blob a98bf3503443ea6a69779fef1f6204fdae913124
```

Comment: Actually, it's *theoretically* possible to create a commit which hashes to the same SHA-1 value which some other commit (the one being "attacked" to be eventually subverted). An attacker has freedom to inject any number of bogus blobs to form a tree object which hashes to such a value to make the whole commit hash to a target value.  Even though I beleive this task is computationally infeasible, an attacker would have full *physical* access to the repository to craft such an attack: I think it's impossible to *replace* a commit using the Git wire protocol.

Comment: “to make Git accept it” — so, you are saying that git checks that contents of the blob match the identifier-hash of the blob?

Comment: @kostix Yes, due to how hashes work there is obviously the possibility for conflicts. And even if it’s possible to find collisions for SHA-1 (that is two objects A, B which hash to the same values), it’s incredibly harder to do so when one of those objects is known (i.e. find another object which hashes to the same hash). So it’s very, very unlikely.

Comment: @HoverHell I just tested this to see *when* Git verifies the hashes. It doesn’t do during normal local work (e.g. when you check-out files). It does however raise erros when cloning a corrupt repository (*“error: unable to find <hash>”*). You can also always perform a verification of all (local) objects by running `git fsck`.